# On the width of the Catalan monoid and the rank of K-groups of the Furstenberg transformation group

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, semigroups-and-monoids, posets

The semigroup algebra of the Catalan monoid is isomorphic to the incidence algebra of $P_n$, where $P_n$ is the poset consisting of subsets of  { 1,...,n } where for two subsets $X \leq Y$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality and if X= {x_1 < ... < x_k } and Y= {y_1 < ... < y_k } we have $x_i \leq y_i$ for $i=1,...,k$. This is for example proved in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06531.pdf. Recall that the width of a poset is the maximum size of an antichain.

I noted that the width of the poset $P_n$ starts with 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 13, 20, 32, 52, 90, 152 for $n=1,...,11$ and this leads to the sequence https://oeis.org/A084239 of the rank of K-groups of the Furstenberg transformation group of the $n$-torus. See table 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4473.pdf .

> Question 1: Is this true for all $n$? Is there a deeper explanation? Does the width have a homoogical interpretation for the Catalan monoid?

The poset $P_n$ has $n+1$ connected components, for each of the $k$-subsets and one can restrict to find antichains in those subsets and put them together. But I am more curious whether there is a deeper connection to the $K$-group sequence or is this just random?
One might also ask about other nice properties of $P_n$. I noted that appending a minimum and maximum to $P_n$, one obtains a lattice.

The width of $P_n$ is equal to the maximal number of covers an element can have in the distributive lattice of order ideals $L(P_n)$ of $P_n$.

> Question 2: Does the incidence algebra of $L(P_n)$ have an algebraic meaning in relation to the Catalan monoid?

> Question 3: Is the Coxeter matrix of $L(P_n)$ periodic?

Question 3 has a positive answer for $n=1,2,3,4$ and the periods are given by 6,12,30,42 in that case.

(Small values suggest that also the Coxeter matrix of $P_n$ might be periodic, but that might be not so good evidence since the connected compoenent have not many points for small $n$.)

Comment: You might look at the answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193913/is-there-a-standard-name-for-this-poset which gives another interpretation of this poset in terms of well known geometry.

Comment: The fact that this algebra is an incidence algebra was o think first proved by Hivert and Thiery.  The proof you linked to is just the shortest one.

Comment: The poset $P_{n,k}$ that's discussed Benjamin Steinberg is the interval of Young's lattice between the empty and a rectangular shapes partition. Using geometry, Stanley shows these posets are Sperner in http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf. This makes computing the width easy (it's then the maximum size of a rank of the poset).

Comment: Again, if we break your $P_{n}$ into the $P_{n,k}$, then the widths are given by https://oeis.org/A067059 by Stanley's Spernicity result. https://oeis.org/A084239 is the sum of the diagonals of https://oeis.org/A067059

Comment: You can translate it in a way that doesn't mention $K_0$ or $K_1$. Suppose that $A$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $a_{i,j}=1$ if $i=j$ or $j=i+1$. Then the claim is that the largest antichain in $P_{n,r}$ is the same as the dimension of the kernel of $\bigwedge^r A-I$.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks, that seems to be the explanation to answer question 1. If you want you can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, the fact that the rank of the kernel of $\bigwedge^r A-I$ and the number of half sized partitions agree is proven in section 6.2 of the Reihani and Milnes paper referenced in the Oeis link.

Comment: The proof of proposition 6.30 in the Reihani-Milnes paper, is essentially very close to Stanley's proof of Spernicity for $P_{n,r}$. In particular the observation that A084239 is the sum of the diagonals of A067059 seems to be just as hard as the computation of the latter. I wonder if there is a more direct route.

Answer (score 4):

The distributive lattice $L(k,n-k) := [\varnothing,(n-k)^k]$, the interval between the empty partition and the rectangular shape $(n-k)^k$ in [Young's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_lattice), is the same as the poset of subsets of $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $k$ ordered by $\{x_1<\cdots<x_k\}\leq \{y_1<\cdots<y_k\}$ iff $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$. We also have $L(k,n-k)=J([k]\times[n-k])$, the distributive lattice of order ideals of the product $[k]\times[n-k]$ of two chains. Finally, and perhaps most importantly, $L(k,n-k)$ is the Bruhat order on the cells of the Grasmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(k,n)$.

Your $P_n$ is a disjoint union of these $L(k,n-k)$.

In ["Weyl groups, the Hard Lefschetz Theorem, and the Sperner property"](http://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf), Stanley proved that $L(k,n-k)$ is Sperner, i.e., the maximum size of an antichain of this poset is the maximum size of one of its rank. (He proves more, namely, the strong Sperner property, and in a more general context of parabolic quotients of Weyl groups, using some basic geometry of generalized flag manifolds.)

The maximum size of a rank of $L(k,n-k)$ is easily seen to be given by the OEIS sequence https://oeis.org/A084239. Since https://oeis.org/A084239 is a sum of diagonals of https://oeis.org/A084239, this explains your observations about $P_n$.

A lot is known about $L(k,n-k)$, because of its connection to representation theory/geometry. For instance, $[k]\times[n-k]$ is a so-called "minuscule poset," which implies a lot of nice properties for $J([k]\times[n-k])$: see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669884800372) of Proctor.

Similarly, your observation about the Coxeter transform being periodic seems to be proved by Yildirim in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10632) in the more general context of minuscule posets.

**EDIT**: Ah, sorry, the paper of Yildirim addresses the periodicity of the Coxeter transform for $L(k,n-k)=J([k]\times[n-k])$. For $J(P_n)$, I bet what you observed only happens for small values of $n$.